# Android Studio FreeMarker Templates by plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

I created FreeMarker template like Activity Template.
For use it I must put it in AndroidStudio\plugins\android\lib\templates\other (for Windows).
Main problem is template will be deleted on Android Studio update.
I tried create plugin for Android Studio.
In plugin I can put single file template in folder  `fileTemplates`, and after set up I can use it.
But with FreeMarker it doesn't work. May be I do something wrong?